# How to access "properties" from Glassfish Virtual Server config?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

In Glassfish Admin GUI -> Configurations -> server-config -> Virtual Servers -> server, I can add key/value entries to "Additional Properties".

How can I access them from within my web app?

They seem neither to be in System.getProperties() nor in InitialContext.lookup() with "mykey" or "java:comp/env/mykey".

I'd like to access them as JNDI java:comp/env/... variable, is that possible?

Comment: maybe if you found something, please post the solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

it looks like those "additional properties" are NOT accessible from application and you can only use predefined properties.You can find list of available properties [here](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/branches/asadmin/v3-docs/common/src/main/resources/en/help/ref-virtualserverprops.html)

Answer (score 0):

I walked into the same problem a while back. The only solution for me was to put the properties in the "WEB_INF" folder. From here I was able to retrieve it trough a servlet. The problem seems to originate in the fact that JAVA-EE projects are deployed in a great variety of places/folder.

You might find something else with class loaders:
[Reading properties from tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280787/reading-properties-from-tomcat)

Comment: I wanted to have different Glassfish Virtual Hosts to use the same .war file for different domainnames but with slightly different configurations depending on which virtual server receives the request. Hence the need to access a property from the virtual server configuration page.