# Separate JVM properties for each java program on same JVM

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm running two web applications in tomat host process, which means In my opinion should have two separate programs, one for each application.

Another thing is both apps have a JVM property used which I want to be app specific.

```
//common-service library used in both web-apps
public class CommonService {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CommonService.class);

    static {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        logger.debug("CommonService initialization for {}" , uuid);
        System.setProperty("key1", "value1-"+ uuid);
    }
}
```

When I deploy the wars for each app and see the value for `key1` property it is overriden by the second application loaded.

As I'm showing here, 
when app1 is loaded, the value for property `key1`

[image: value1]

when app2 is loaded, the value for property `key1` 
[image: valu2]

**But after app2 is loaded, it overrides `key1` for app1.**

[image: valu1_for_app1]

The code is pretty simple for above,

```
public class Service1Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CommonService commonService = new CommonService();
        System.out.println("Service1 key1= " + System.getProperty("key1"));
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + System.getProperty("key1")+ "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

So, it seems I can have JVM parameters global only in single JVM, but I have multiple services running on my server where each service needs to have its own set of JVM parameters, based on which there is another api which actually uses that JVM property.

Comment: Not sure what you are really asking for ... but maybe it would help if your services would not use System properties, but rely on different property files; maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280787/reading-properties-from-tomcat ?

Comment: `properties for each java process on same JVM` JVM is one process (not counting LWP). There is no such thing like more processes on one JVM

Comment: That is right, system properties are per JVM - you are looking something at application level

Comment: You can only set System properties on the command line globally. You could make them local to applications, but how would you set them?

Answer (score 2):

For application properties, you don't want to use VM parameters.  As you have discovered, these are global to the entire container.  Instead, you should use a properties file which is loaded when the application loads.  One approach I like to use is loading a resource bundle into a static Map.  Let's say you had an "application.properties" file in the WEB-INF/classes directory.  Like this:

```
//common-service library used in both web-apps
public class CommonService {

    public static Map< String, String > APPLICATION_PROPERTIES = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "application" );
        for( String key : bundle.keySet() ) {
          APPLICATION_PROPERTIES.put( key, ( String )bundle.getObject( key ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to access an application property, you do it in your code like this:

```
String key1Value = CommonService.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES.get( "key1" );
```

Comment: Well, I know what you're saying. The problem in my case was some third API was expecting `-Dkey1=valueX` to be set and process that way, which is weird, and looks bad design when I'm running my application inside the same tomcat process. I think the System properties would be different when I run using `java SomeClass`. I believe I tested that.