# Resolving path in tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat9

I have this piece of code:

`Paths.get("conf/app.properties").toAbsolutePath()`

When I run it in Tomcat 7, it properly resolves to a relative directory, using `$CATALINA_HOME`. But when I run it in Tomcat 9, it "resolves" to `/conf/app.properties` which obviously doesn't exist. How do I get Tomcat 9 to properly resolve the path?

Comment: I checked the tomcat migration guides (7 to 8 and 8 to 9), but couldn't find anything relating to resolving file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this answer - seems to be doing something close to what you need:
[Reading properties from tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280787/reading-properties-from-tomcat)

I came up quickly from that to something like:

```
<%= new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf").getAbsolutePath() %>
```

Comment: This works, but it feels wrong. Shouldn't tomcat be taking care of automatically doing that?

Comment: To me having the server folder as a Java property is as correct as it could be. Whether your application should be messing with the server configuration is a totally different story ;)